# Break columns to the next page

Tags: c#, migradoc

I am about to create a table with a dynamic numbers of columns, how can I break the columns to the next page when I have to many columns?

I create PDF reports using MigraDoc.

```cs
Section section = m_pdfBuilder.m_pdfDocument.AddSection();

Table table = new Table();
section.AddParagraph(m_tableTitle);
Unit width = section.PageSetup.PageWidth;

for (int col = 0; col < getMaxColumn(); col++)
{
    table.AddColumn();
}

try
{
    for (int _row = 0; _row < getMaxRow(); _row++)
    {
        table.AddRow();
    }

    table.Borders.Visible = true;
    table.SetEdge(0, 0, 0, 0, Edge.Box, BorderStyle.Single, 0.75, MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Color.Empty);

    // add the created Table to the PdfDocument
    section.Add(table);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   int i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of MigraDoc does not support breaking columns to a new page.

A simple workaround is increasing the width of the page as needed. Then all table columns can be viewed in the PDF viewer on a single page side by side.